# Sci fi/ fantasy book, older book, some sort of flesh eating swarm

Tags: story-identification

I remember very little about this book, I read it when I was a kid. It was some sort of alien world, where animals kept getting striped bare to their bones and nobody could figure out why. Then it gets found out it's like this massive swarm of bugs that essentially fly over something for a few seconds and when it's stripped bare they move on. I wish I could remember more, I mostly just remember I really enjoyed reading it. It is not Prey by Crichton.

Comment: Do you remember when you were a kid? Was that the 90s? 80s? Maybe the 50s? This would help narrow down the range of time the book may have been published in. Also, can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can edit in any more details. Every bit counts in helping us identify your story!

Answer (score 8):

This has some similarity to ['Beowulf's Children'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf%27s_Children), Larry Niven's sequel to 'The Legacy of Heorot'. The stories are about a human colony called Avalon. The colony planet fauna have evolved a blood supercharger compound which when consumed by the local equivalent of bees causes them to behave like the bug swarm mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like Beast Master's Ark. It's written by Lyn McConchie, following an Andre Norton book. It was published in 2003.https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/462382.Beast_Master_s_Ark

Comment: This was my first thought too.

Answer (score 1):

Might it have been "Dust" by Charles Pellegrino?  Much fits but it doesn't happen on an alien world.

[https://www.amazon.com/Dust-Charles-R-Pellegrino/dp/0380787423](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380787423)

Answer (score 0):

Edmund Cooper's Venom of Argus included 'Pirahna Bugs', a swarm of which could strip an animal to the bones in seconds...

It's one of a four part series about a team of astronauts proving planets safe for colonisation